# How do I get twiml.say to talk to person I've dialed

Tags: twilio

I have a function that is supposed to talk to a 911 dispatcher but doesn't say anything until the "dispatcher" has hung up. How do I get twiml.say to happen right after dialing?

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

      // Wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
      // if is a valid phone number
      const attr = isAValidPhoneNumber(event.To) ? 'number' : 'client';
var got = require('got');

console.log('from', event.From.slice(7))
got('https://911callbot.com/api/get_incident?date_code_and_code='+event.From.slice(7), {'json': true})
  .then(function(response) {
   const dial = twiml.dial({
        callerId: context.CALLER_ID,
        record: 'record-from-ringing-dual'
      });
      console.log('RESPONSE', response.body)
      console.log('test', response.body.code)
      response_body = response.body
      dial[attr]({}, event.To);
      code = response_body[0] + ' ' + response_body[1] + ' ' + response_body[2] + ' ' + response_body[3]
      msg = 'This is 911callbot.com again 911callbot.com the incident code is '+response_body['code']+' again the incident code is '+code+' the address is '+response_body['address']+' again the address is '+response_body['address']+' caller is reporting '+response_body['what_reporting'];
      console.log(msg)
      twiml.say(msg);
      callback(null, twiml)
    })
};

/**
* Checks if the given value is valid as phone number
* @param {Number|String} number
* @return {Boolean}
*/
function isAValidPhoneNumber(number) {
  return /^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/.test(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To get Twilio to start reading out a [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) straight away, it needs to be the first thing you add to the `VoiceResponse`.

This is the core of your callback right now:

```
  const dial = twiml.dial({
    callerId: context.CALLER_ID,
    record: 'record-from-ringing-dual'
  });
  console.log('RESPONSE', response.body)
  console.log('test', response.body.code)
  response_body = response.body
  dial[attr]({}, event.To);
  code = response_body[0] + ' ' + response_body[1] + ' ' + response_body[2] + ' ' + response_body[3]
  msg = 'This is 911callbot.com again 911callbot.com the incident code is '+response_body['code']+' again the incident code is '+code+' the address is '+response_body['address']+' again the address is '+response_body['address']+' caller is reporting '+response_body['what_reporting'];
  console.log(msg)
  twiml.say(msg);
  callback(null, twiml)
```

You want to switch that around so that you call `twiml.say

```
  code = response_body[0] + ' ' + response_body[1] + ' ' + response_body[2] + ' ' + response_body[3]
  msg = 'This is 911callbot.com again 911callbot.com the incident code is '+response_body['code']+' again the incident code is '+code+' the address is '+response_body['address']+' again the address is '+response_body['address']+' caller is reporting '+response_body['what_reporting'];
  console.log(msg)
  twiml.say(msg);
  const dial = twiml.dial({
    callerId: context.CALLER_ID,
    record: 'record-from-ringing-dual'
  });
  console.log('RESPONSE', response.body)
  console.log('test', response.body.code)
  response_body = response.body
  dial[attr]({}, event.To);
  callback(null, twiml);
```

Comment: will this talk to both callers? how do i can speaking to both callers on answer by 911?

Comment: person "calls" 911 via webrtc I call 911 and then on answer by 911 want to speak the 911 caller's info

Comment: This will not speak the message to both people no. To do that is a little awkward right now. You'd need to set this initial call up as a conference call and then, once both participants had entered, call in as a third party and connect to a script that says the message. I'd be wary of this method though, as you are potentially calling 911 and leaving the agent waiting for the other party to connect before they hear anything, which could be a waste of their time.